# Auto Generated Value is setting to NULL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to SQL in my project and it's the first time I've used it. I set up a relatively standard database and dropped my tables into the form, this is part of the Test definition:

[image]

This is the properties panel for TestID:

[image]

However, this code:

```
Test test = new Test();
db.Tests.InsertOnSubmit(test);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Despite TestID being the only NOT NULL field, it's yelling this at me when that code is ran:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll
Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TestID'`

Is there something that I've obviously done wrong? I can easily provide more information if necessary and more pictures or code, but I think this is all that should be necessary to diagnose to some extent.

I've looked around and even seen screenshots of people just changing Auto Generated Value to true for a working solution... I'm not sure why it isn't working for me.

Thanks, sorry if I left any important information out, will add it in the morning if I did, tiredness tends to make me bad at paying attention to details.

Comment: I assume you've already checked that TestID is setup correctly in your actual database schema as an auto-incremented field?

Comment: Ah... Crap. That turned out to be the problem. Sorry, I had tried with IDENTITY previously before I'd done Auto Generated Value and it didn't like it, and I forgot to try afterwards. Thanks :)

Comment: Drop it as an answer if you have a chance and I'll accept it for you :)

Comment: Be advised that LINQ to SQL isn't under development, and hasn't been for several years. It's pretty much a dead end at this point, so I wouldn't invest too much effort in learning it. Microsoft has transitioned to Entity Framework.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the warning, didn't realise that. Should be okay for finishing this project off, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything that you described in your question is correct. If you are receiving this error I would start at the beginning and validate that your database schema is properly setup to auto-increment the identity column you created.